# How to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 19.10

There are many similar questions: this one is about "why do the recommended answers not work in 2021" ?  Based on many similar questions I ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo do-release-upgrade
```

That downloaded a lot of packages- many of them for 18.04 for some reason. But then at end the result was:

```
...
Setting up libnvidia-ifr1-435:i386 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-435:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-435:i386 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-dkms-435 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
.. Setting up nvidia-utils-435:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-driver-435 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-435:amd64 (455.45.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.30-0ubuntu2.2) ...
..Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.133ubuntu10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-64-generic
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
```

I then tried:  `sudo do-release-upgrade`

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Is there a procedure to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 that actually works?

Comment: Yes, as 19.10 is EOL back up all your important stuff to some where safe, download the iso for the version you want (suggest 20.04 LTS) and use it to do a vanilla installation from scratch.

Comment: @24601  Yea I was about to start setting up for that. It's typically big-time drama to figure out writing to a physical device. system does not have DVD, i'll try to do thumb drive

Comment: There's plenty of links in AU to advise on that. `hwe-support-status` in terminal on my 20.04 LTS system reports support until April 2025. IMO best to stick with LTS versions if upgrading from unsupported versions is  going to be a pain